# UDP Proxy in C#? Needs a little assistance

Tags: c#, proxy, udp, pipe

Can someone spot what I did wrong here? Seems to only create one instance of the sockets not two.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace UdpProxy
{
    class Program
    {
        public static UdpClient server = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int localPort = 7900;
            IPEndPoint remoteSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4001);

            IPAddress tempAddress;

            IPAddress.TryParse("OUT_GOING_IP/HOST_GOES_HERE", out tempAddress);
            remoteSender.Address = tempAddress;
            remoteSender.Port = 7900;

            // Display some information
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome! Starting Upd proxy server.");
            Console.WriteLine("Local port: " + localPort);
            Console.WriteLine("Remote ip: " + remoteSender.Address.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Remote port: " + remoteSender.Port);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit.");

            // Create UDP client
            UdpClient client = new UdpClient(localPort);
            UdpState state = new UdpState(client, remoteSender);
            state.setRemote(remoteSender);
            // Start async receiving
            client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(DataReceivedClient), state);



            // Wait for any key to terminate application
            Console.ReadKey();
            client.Close();
        }

        private static void DataReceivedClient(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            UdpClient c = (UdpClient)((UdpState)ar.AsyncState).c;
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e; //local ip and random port.
            IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).remote;
            byte[] receiveBytes = c.EndReceive(ar, ref ipEndPoint);

            // Convert data to ASCII and print in console
            string receivedText = BitConverter.ToString(receiveBytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Client 2 Server = " + receivedText);


            if (server == null)
            {
                // Create UDP client
                server = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
                UdpState stateServer = new UdpState(server, remoteIPEndPoint);
                server.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(DataReceiveServer), stateServer);
                server.Connect(remoteIPEndPoint);

            }

            server.Send(receiveBytes, receiveBytes.Length);

            // Restart listening for udp data packages
            c.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(DataReceivedClient), ar.AsyncState);
        }


        private static void DataReceiveServer(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            UdpClient c = (UdpClient)((UdpState)ar.AsyncState).c;
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e; //local ip and random port.
            byte[] receiveBytes = c.EndReceive(ar, ref ipEndPoint);

            // Convert data to ASCII and print in console
            string receivedText = BitConverter.ToString(receiveBytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Server 2 Client = " + receivedText);


            c.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            c.Send(receiveBytes, receiveBytes.Length);

            // Restart listening for udp data packages
            c.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(DataReceiveServer), ar.AsyncState);
        }
    }
}
```

supporting helper class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace UdpProxy
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Simple implementation of the UdpState class mentioned on 
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8s04db1(v=VS.80).aspx
    /// </summary>
    internal class UdpState
    {
        internal UdpState(UdpClient c, IPEndPoint e)
        {
            this.c = c;
            this.e = e;
        }

        internal void setRemote(IPEndPoint remote)
        {
            this.remote = remote;
        }

        internal UdpClient c;
        internal IPEndPoint e;
        internal IPEndPoint remote;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it here is the solution if anyone wants to learn how I fixed it.. Please note this is probably the only UDP Proxy on all of google if you stumbled upon this.. that is coded in C#.. easily ported to VB.NET with online .NET converter

Be happy this code works ;)

Sure it's not efficient because it doesn't use events.. like ReceiveAsync/EndReceive.

Only downfall to not using Aysnchronize events.. is that you see below the working code.. will have to be stuck in a infinite loop.. and it will burn your CPU cycles.. easily fixed with a Thread.Sleep(10).. (don't set to high or you will have udp lag)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace UdpProxy
{
    class Program
    {
        public static IPEndPoint m_listenEp = null;
        public static EndPoint m_connectedClientEp = null;
        public static IPEndPoint m_sendEp = null;
        public static Socket m_UdpListenSocket = null;
        public static Socket m_UdpSendSocket = null;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Creates Listener UDP Server
            m_listenEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 7900);
            m_UdpListenSocket = new Socket(m_listenEp.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            m_UdpListenSocket.Bind(m_listenEp);

            //Connect to zone IP EndPoint
            m_sendEp = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("REMOTE_IP_GOES_HERE"), 7900);
            m_connectedClientEp = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 7900);

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];

            while (true)
            {
                if (m_UdpListenSocket.Available > 0)
                {

                    int size = m_UdpListenSocket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref m_connectedClientEp); //client to listener

                    if (m_UdpSendSocket == null)
                    {
                        // Connect to UDP Game Server.
                        m_UdpSendSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                    }

                    m_UdpSendSocket.SendTo(data, size, SocketFlags.None, m_sendEp); //listener to server.

                }

                if (m_UdpSendSocket != null && m_UdpSendSocket.Available > 0)
                {
                    int size = m_UdpSendSocket.Receive(data); //server to client.

                    m_UdpListenSocket.SendTo(data, size, SocketFlags.None, m_connectedClientEp); //listner

                }
            }


            // Wait for any key to terminate application
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thread.Sleep is usually a bad idea. It just say: "don't run this code again before 10ms have passed". But there's absolutely no guarantee it will run right at the end of these 10ms. Plus on most system the ThreadSleep precision is a multiple of 16ms: Basically any number you would put "greater" than 0 would mean a minimum of 16ms.

Comment: How would I make it better? can you show me How I would make this use events?

Comment: This msdn article can be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300760.aspx

Comment: Short of just using BeginRead, there is probably a simple way to wait for data... I think select() works for UDP, for example.  If you go with Thread.Sleep() I recommend setting a flag anytime data is received, and only calling Sleep if no data received in the prior loop.  This way if you have a lot of data streaming at any given time, it will not sleep until it catches up with all data waiting in internal Windows/winsock buffers.